# Hibernate custom HQL for this mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

I have following tables

```
------------
BAR
------------
ID
number

------------
ZOO
------------
ID

------------
FOO
------------
ID

------------
MAPPER
------------
ID
FOO
BAR
ZOO
```

Now I want to fetch all ZOO for particular FOO  So I will do

```
select ZOO from MAPPER where zoo = someZoo
```

but now I want these ZOO sorted based on vote number so SQL would be

```
SELECT FOOBAR.ZOO
FROM  mapper AS mapper,
BAR AS bar
WHERE mapper.FOO=SOME_VALUE AND mapper.BAR=bar.id order by bar.number desc
```

But now I want to do it in DB independent way in Hibernate How would I go ?

I have entities mapped setup I am using Spring Hibernate Template Support

```
public class Foo{
Long id;
}


public class Zoo{
Long id;
}

public class Bar{
Long id;
Long num;
}

public class Mapper{
Long id;
Long foo;
Long bar;
Long zoo;

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the entity code, rather than pseudo DB tables?

Comment: @James DW Added basic model classes without mapping and stuffs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class Mapper should be:

```
public class Mapper {
    Long id;
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    Zoo zoo;
}
```

Now, you can write the following HSQL query:

```
select mapper.zoo from Mapper mapper where mapper.foo=:foo order by mapper.bar.num desc
```